# As in Yii 2.0 (Menu :: Widget ) use the span?

Tags: php, html, css, yii

When I use the following code, the end result is " TEST " and should be "TEST" in the tags .

```
echo Menu::widget([
                                        'options' => ['id' => 'navigate'],
                                        'items' => [
                                            [
                                                'label' => '<span>TEST</span>',
                                                'url' => ['#'],
                                            ],
                                            ['label' => '<span>TEST2</span>', 'url' => ['#']],
                                        ],
                                    ]);
```

I know I should use encodeLabel but does not work and returns an error. Can you do to help?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
echo Menu::widget([
            'options' => ['id' => 'navigate'],
            'encodeLabels' => false,
            'items' => [
                [
                    'label' => '<span>TEST</span>',
                    'url' => ['#'],

                ],
                ['label' => '<span>TEST2</span>', 'url' => ['#']],
            ],
        ]);
```